# Command text was not set for the command object - work in other places

Tags: jscript

I'm getting the above error for some reason I can't understand. I have commented out after Connect() down to disconnect and it all runs fine, so I know the problem is there somewhere. My code is:

```
var sixMonth = parseInt(currentDate.getMonth() - 6);
sixMonth++;
var reviewDate = year + "-" + sixMonth + "-" + day;
var d1;
var d2 = new Date(reviewDate);
var intListViewIndex9 = 0;

Connect();
var EOF = 0;

RecordSet = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

//set the source    
RecordSet.Source = statement;

//set the conection for the record set to use
RecordSet.ActiveConnection = ObjConnection;

//Open your RecordSet (i.e. Execute the query)
RecordSet.Open;

//declare the statement
statement = "SELECT AccessDate from screens.signoff WHERE BadgeNo = '" +               BadgeNo + "'";

while (RecordSetas.EOF == false){
    accessDate = RecordSet.Fields("AccessDate").Value;
    d1 = new Date(accessDate);

    if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()) {
        SQL("UPDATE screens.signoff SET Recertify = '1' WHERE BadgeNo = '" + BadgeNo + "'");
    }

    //Move to the next record in the RecordSet
    intListViewIndex9 = intListViewIndex9 + 1;
    RecordSet.MoveNext; 
}

//Close the RecordSet
RecordSet.Close;
//Destroy the objRecordSet object variable from memory
RecordSet = {};

disconect();
```

I have used this structure in other places and it works absolutely fine so I'm lost as to why this isn't.

Here are the other defined bits that are called as a part of the SQL.

```
var ObjConnection;

function Connect(){
    ObjConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    SQLlook()
    ObjConnection.Open ("DSN=SQL");
}

function disconect(){
    //Close the Database Connection
    ObjConnection.Close;
    //Destroy the objConnection object variable from memory
    ObjConnection = {};
}
```

Comment: please tag with the correct programming language, the vast majority of this code is not SQL, and by the sounds of it the problem is not in the SQL part. I assume it's javascript?

Comment: anyway, rather obviously, you set `RecordSet.Source = statement;` before you actually populate statement. `statement = ...` is going to need to come before that line.

Comment: also `RecordSetas.EOF == false` - is this a typo? There's no variable called RecordSetas

Comment: Changed tag to correct language - jscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADyson was right, rather than set RecordSet.source = statement and then declare it I just set the actual SQL command after (RecordSet.Source = "Select etc etc")

RescordSetas was also a typo